# fread writing the value 0 into allocated memory, returns large value

Tags: c, file-io

```
short * left = malloc(sizeof(short));
short * right = malloc(sizeof(short));
short * combined = malloc(sizeof(short));
FILE * inputFile = fopen(inputf, "r");;
FILE * outputFile = fopen(outputf, "w");;

while(1){
    int resultLeft = fread(left, sizeof(short), 1, inputFile);
    int resultRight = fread(right, sizeof(short), 1, inputFile);

    //if we reached the end of the file, close files and break the loop.
    if (resultLeft != 1 || resultRight != 1){
        fclose(inputFile);
        fclose(outputFile);
        break;
    }

    //*combined = operation;

    fwrite(combined, sizeof(short), 1, outputFile);
    fwrite(combined, sizeof(short), 1, outputFile);
}
```

I've been working at this for hours, and had other people take looks at it, but I can't figure this out. The gist is that I need to read pairs of Shorts (purely bytes), combine them using an operation, then write the combination twice into a new file. The only problem is that the fread functions here write the value "0" into the allocated memory for left and right.

An earlier example in the code, `fread(headerbuffer, 11 * sizeof(int), 1, inputFile);` works just fine, leading to just more confusion.

Comment: You're *sure* the bytes being read were previously written with equivalent `fwrite` functionality ? a hexdump of your source data would go a long way in understanding whether thats true.

Comment: Yeah, the input file would help. Also some printouts of the values after the reading..

Comment: what is inputf and outputf ? are their no extensions for them? also you should check for some error while opening a file by putting a condition there like -> if(inputFile!=NULL)...

Comment: I suspect `fread` failure - (**man fread**) - If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count **(or zero)**.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: he appears to be checking for errors 3 lines below (if either call errors then their return value will not be `1`).

Comment: The content of `*combined` is never set, so `fwrite(combined, sizeof(short), 1, outputFile);` is writing uninitiated data.  Further, the data read into `*left` and `*right` is never used.

Comment: Input file is a .wav file.

The operation for combined is a simple `*combined = (left - right) / 2`, but never works because left and right only have the value of 0 written into them.

The code is meant to remove the center track from a stereo sound file, hopefully removing the vocals from a piece of music.

Comment: Using ftell(), I can see the filestream pointer is moving 4 bytes at a time (as it's supposed to). I also made sure a file was being opened into inputFile, and it is there.